# Query order by count

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

ID  Name

- 1 Asd
- 2 Qwe
- 3 Asd
- 4 Asd
- 5 Qwe
- 6 Dsa

i need a query returns group order by count like;

ID  Name

- 1 Asd
- 2 Qwe
- 3 Dsa

Comment: i've tried SELECT name FROM users k1 JOIN ( SELECT name, COUNT(*) cnt  FROM users GROUP BY name) k2 ON ( k1.name = k2.name )
ORDER BY k2.cnt DESC

Comment: Then why didn't you include this statement in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it might be helpful,

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS total, id, Name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Name   
ORDER BY COUNT(Name) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1  AS ID,
       NameList.iName
FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT iName, COUNT(iName) AS iCount 
       FROM people 
       GROUP BY iName 
       ORDER BY iCount DESC) NameList, 
      (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

change this subquery

```
      (SELECT DISTINCT iName, COUNT(iName) AS iCount 
       FROM people 
       GROUP BY iName 
       ORDER BY iCount DESC)
```

to the table with the list of name.

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
SELECT id, Name FROM user
GROUP BY Name   
ORDER BY COUNT(Name) DESC;
```